# Memory Referencing Bug Example

Tags: c++, c, cpu-architecture

```
typedef struct
{
    int a[2];
    double d;
}struct_t;

double fun(int i)
{
    volatile struct_t s;
    s.d = 3.14;
    s.a[i] = 1073741824;
    return s.d;
}
```

[image]

I met this example while learning the course about CSAPP. The explanation is shown below. But I still cannot figure it out.
[image]

Comment: Think about the sizeof int, the sizeof double, and what memory is guaranteed to be writable in this example.

Comment: What's your actual question?  What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: How about `double fun(int i) { if (i < 0 || i > 1) {.. handle error ..} ...}`?

Comment: What is confusing you? The explanation is mixing bytes and bits. a[i] is a byte, d0, d1... are bits. If you write a beyond a[1], you're out of range; you're writing in the space allocated to d. If you write beyond a[3], you're writing in a space that does not belong to your structure.

Comment: It is telling you that you won't always get an access violation when you exceed the array bounds.  This scenario also happens on stack based arrays.  You will only get it when you go outside the stack frame/allocated memory

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at what your struct looks like in memory. Assuming `int` is 4 bytes (as that's what the end behavior leads us to believe), here it is:

```
byte 0,1,2,3: a[0]
byte 4,5,6,7: a[1]
byte 8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F: d
```

`fun(1)` creates this structure, sets `d` to 3.14 (`0x40091EB851EB851F`), and then sets `a[i]` to `1073741824` (`0x40000000`). There are no run-time checks to ensure that `a[i]` points to a location within `a[2]`, which can cause problems (as demonstrated here). 0 and 1 will not change anything, as both will write to `a[0]` and `a[1]` respectively. However, if you write to `a[2]`, you'll be overlapping into the space occupied by `d`. By writing to `a[2]`, you replace the top 4 bytes of `d`.

*Note that the sizes on your system may be different, e.g. `int` may be 2 bytes, but the gist of the issue is the same.*

Eventually, when you get to `a[4]`, `d` returns to 3.14. This is because you've completely stepped over `d`. The stack beyond this point is unallocated, so the program terminates with a segmentation fault.

**TL;DR: You're writing to memory that overlaps with your double.**

(Note - This is an example of what NOT to do. This is undefined behavior, and there's no guarantee as to what a given system will do in this case.)

Comment: From an accounting standpoint your not off, but from a C - standard standpoint you invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to access an array element outside the defined bounds.

Comment: That is true. The CSAPP course is accessing an out-of-bounds array to demonstrate a point, and is probably not aiming to encourage code that induces undefined behavior (at least, I hope so).

Comment: Undefined behavior is usually frowned upon in stackOverflow. I think it's getting a little out of hand, this is a perfectly educational example, as long as you add disclaimers that different systems may exhibit different behavior, and that the explanation shows what happened in a specific case

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `int` is 2 bytes in the OP's example.  It's clearly 4B, because `fun(4)` doesn't affect the `double` at all (it wrote past the end of the struct).  Also, `fun(3)` affected the value significantly, not just modifying some low bits in the mantissa.  The memory layout diagram also confirms this, that `a[]` takes as much space as `d`.